# Select specific date jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, selenium, datepicker

How to select a specific date from the jQuery UI Datepicker? For example I need to choose the current date as ('**from-date**') and one week from current date as ('**to-date**').
The datepicker contains only the days of current month.

Comment: Please share the script for handling date operation and please share source for datepicker

Comment: Go through this link. Hope this will help. <http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automating-custom-controls-datepicker/>

Answer (score 0):

Go to place which open the calendar  and clock and then iterate according to required date and time.

I hope below code work for you.

import java.util.Calendar;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DatePicker {

```
@Test

public void testDAtePicker() throws Exception{

    //DAte and Time to be set in textbox

    String dateTime ="12/07/2014 2:00 PM";

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //button to open calendar

    WebElement selectDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@aria-controls='datetimepicker_dateview']"));

selectDate.click();

//button to move next in calendar

WebElement nextLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='datetimepicker_dateview']//div[@class='k-header']//a[contains(@class,'k-nav-next')]"));

//button to click in center of calendar header

WebElement midLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='datetimepicker_dateview']//div[@class='k-header']//a[contains(@class,'k-nav-fast')]"));

//button to move previous month in calendar

WebElement previousLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='datetimepicker_dateview']//div[@class='k-header']//a[contains(@class,'k-nav-prev')]")); 

    //Split the date time to get only the date part

    String date_dd_MM_yyyy[] = (dateTime.split(" ")[0]).split("/");

    //get the year difference between current year and year to set in calander

    int yearDiff = Integer.parseInt(date_dd_MM_yyyy[2])- Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

    midLink.click();

    if(yearDiff!=0){

        //if you have to move next year

        if(yearDiff>0){

            for(int i=0;i< yearDiff;i++){

                System.out.println("Year Diff->"+i);

                nextLink.click();

            }

        }

        //if you have to move previous year

        else if(yearDiff<0){

            for(int i=0;i< (yearDiff*(-1));i++){

                System.out.println("Year Diff->"+i);

                previousLink.click();

            }

        }

    }

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //Get all months from calendar to select correct one

    List<WebElement> list_AllMonthToBook = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='datetimepicker_dateview']//table//tbody//td[not(contains(@class,'k-other-month'))]"));

    list_AllMonthToBook.get(Integer.parseInt(date_dd_MM_yyyy[1])-1).click();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //get all dates from calendar to select correct one

    List<WebElement> list_AllDateToBook = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='datetimepicker_dateview']//table//tbody//td[not(contains(@class,'k-other-month'))]"));

    list_AllDateToBook.get(Integer.parseInt(date_dd_MM_yyyy[0])-1).click();

    ///FOR TIME

    WebElement selectTime = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@aria-controls='datetimepicker_timeview']"));

    //click time picker button

    selectTime.click();

    //get list of times

    List<WebElement> allTime = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-role='popup'][contains(@style,'display: block')]//ul//li[@role='option']"));

    dateTime = dateTime.split(" ")[1]+" "+dateTime.split(" ")[2];

 //select correct time

    for (WebElement webElement : allTime) {

        if(webElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(dateTime))

        {

            webElement.click();

        }

    }

}
```

}

For more details you can follow below link.

https://www.guru99.com/handling-date-time-picker-using-selenium.html